# How to get around salesforce API limit

Tags: rest, api, google-apps-script, salesforce

I am building a chrome extension/third-party app that needs to read data from salesforce.

One way is to make a API call directly to salesforce whenever a user needs to query something, but this will create a large number of API calls.

What I attempted to do is to pull a ton of data from salesforce into a Google Sheet using the reports API, on an hourly basis, then query the data through Google App Script. But Salesforce's 2000 row limits for Reports and SOQL API, as well as the runtime limits posed by Google App Script, make my life difficult :(

What are the best ways to get data from salesforce for third party extensions?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: If your queries mostly re-read the same data, I would consider building a proxy service with a cache. It would also improve performance.
You'd need a high cache hit rate to make this viable though.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk API can fulfill your needs as it hasn't a limitation on the number of returned rows.